# why loss jump up to nan with swa method?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss

I use SWA methods to train model in pytorch.

SWA: https://pytorch.org/blog/stochastic-weight-averaging-in-pytorch/

my train code's loss jump up to nan immidiately.

model' loss jump up to nan

loss outputs is below.

1.loss: tensor(4.8463, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)

2.loss: tensor(118317.8516, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)

3.loss: tensor(5.7568e+22, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)

4.loss: tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)

without SWA methods,loss don't jump up.
is there any problems in train model's code with SWA method?

I would appreciate any advice,thank you.

```
#batch_size
batch_size=5

#DataLoader
train_dataloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
val_dataloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)

#dict
dataloaders_dict={"train":train_dataloader,"val":val_dataloader}

#example outputs
#train :torch.Size([5, 25, 32, 32])
#target : torch.Size([5])

def train_model_withSWA(net,dataloaders_dict,criterion,optimizer,num_epochs):

    loss_list=[]
    acc_list=[]

    #validation list
    val_loss_list=[]
    val_acc_list=[]


    for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
        print("Epoch{}/{}".format(epoch+1,num_epochs))
        print("--------------------------")

        for phase in ["train","val"]:
            if phase=="train":
                net.train()
            else:
                net.eval()

            epoch_loss=0.0 
            epoch_corrects=0

            #if (epoch==0) and (phase=="train"):
                continue

            for inputs,labels in dataloaders_dict[phase]:
                #optimizerを初期化：
                optimizer.zero_grad()


                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase=="train"): 

                    inputs=inputs.to(device)

                    labels=labels.to(device)



                    outputs=net(inputs)

                    loss=criterion(outputs,labels)
                    print("loss:",loss)

                    _,preds=torch.max(outputs,1)

                    if phase == "train":
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                    epoch_loss += loss.item()*inputs.size(0)
                    epoch_corrects +=torch.sum(preds==labels.data)

            #for swa
            optimizer.swap_swa_sgd() 
            epoch_loss=epoch_loss/len(dataloaders_dict[phase].dataset)
            epoch_acc=epoch_corrects.double()/len(dataloaders_dict[phase].dataset)
            print("{} Loss:{:.4f} Acc:{:.4f}".format(phase,epoch_loss,epoch_acc))

            if phase=="train":
                loss_list.append(epoch_loss.detach().numpy())
                acc_list.append(epoch_acc.detach().numpy())
            else:
                val_loss_list.append(epoch_loss.detach().numpy())
                val_acc_list.append(epoch_acc.detach().numpy())

from torchcontrib.optim import SWA

# ignore warning
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') # set to ignore

#criterion
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
net=net.to(device)

base_opt = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer = SWA(base_opt, swa_start=10, swa_freq=5, swa_lr=0.05)

### train with SWA
train_model_withSWA(net=net,dataloaders_dict=dataloaders_dict,
                    criterion=criterion,
                    optimizer=optimizer,
                    num_epochs=num_epochs)

#model' loss jump up to nan....

#loss: tensor(4.8463, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
#loss: tensor(118317.8516, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
#loss: tensor(5.7568e+22, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
#loss: tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)



# In additional.
I use Self Attention and Positional Encoder code


class Self_Attention(nn.Module):
    """ Self-Attention Layer"""

    def __init__(self, in_dim):
        super(Self_Attention, self).__init__()

        #pointwise convolution
        self.query_conv = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=in_dim, out_channels=in_dim, kernel_size=1)
        self.key_conv = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=in_dim, out_channels=in_dim, kernel_size=1)
        self.value_conv = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=in_dim, out_channels=in_dim, kernel_size=1)

        # softmax
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-2)


        #output = x +gamma*o
        # first:gamma=0
        self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))

    def forward(self, x):

        x=x.to(device)

        X = x

        #B,C',W,H→B,C',N
        proj_query = self.query_conv(X).view(
            X.shape[0], -1, X.shape[2]*X.shape[3])  # size：B,C',N
        proj_query = proj_query.permute(0, 2, 1)  # transpose
        proj_key = self.key_conv(X).view(
            X.shape[0], -1, X.shape[2]*X.shape[3])  # size：B,C',N

        # bmm
        S = torch.bmm(proj_query, proj_key) 

        # 
        attention_map_T = self.softmax(S)  
        attention_map = attention_map_T.permute(0, 2, 1)  

        # Self-Attention Map
        proj_value = self.value_conv(X).view(
            X.shape[0], -1, X.shape[2]*X.shape[3])  # size：B,C,N
        o = torch.bmm(proj_value, attention_map.permute(
            0, 2, 1))

        # Self-Attention Map
        o = o.view(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2], X.shape[3])
        out = x+self.gamma*o
        #print("gamma:",self.gamma)
        return out, attention_map




class PositionalEncoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, d_model=300, max_seq_len=256):
        super(PositionalEncoder,self).__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model  


        pe = torch.zeros(max_seq_len, d_model)

        # GPU
        device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        pe = pe.to(device)

        for pos in range(max_seq_len):
            for i in range(0, d_model, 2):
                pe[pos, i] = math.sin(pos / (10000 ** ((2 * i)/d_model)))
                pe[pos, i + 1] = math.cos(pos /
                                          (10000 ** ((2 * (i + 1))/d_model)))

        #
        self.pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)

        #
        self.pe.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, x):
        x=x.to(device)
        ret = math.sqrt(self.d_model)*x + self.pe
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Without normalization in data_preprocessing,loss don't jump up to nan.

this can be caused by my preprocessing error. I don't understand reration with normalization and loss's jump up in SWA method even now...
Im sorry for the mistake.